How do I remove a pocket door with double rails?
I am trying to take out a pocket door to clean it up, repaint it and replace the hardware. The pocket door has rails on either side of the rollers. I’ve taken off all the trim and I still can’t access any hardware on it. Next thing I can think of is to start removing drywall. It does have screws that it would seem like they hold the rollers into the door, but unscrewing them does nothing.





you removed those screws?

Judging by the slots cut in the door slabs, you'll need to remove the pins we see in the second photo, which I assume pass through a hanger plate as we see in the last photo.
If you removed a screw from that location, try spinning it back in a short distance and using it to pull the pin. If that doesn't work, try some small tools. It may help to place a wedge of some sort under the door at each pin location to lighten the load.
